# mysql IN clause treating value as a Unknown column error

Tags: mysql

I have a statement like this

```
SELECT `daycare attendance table`.Date, `daycare attendance table`.StartTime, `daycare attendance table`.EndTime, `daycare attendance table`.DropoffID, `daycare attendance table`.PickupID, `daycare attendance table`.LastName, `daycare attendance table`.FirstName, `daycare attendance table`.ItemNo, Students.SubStatus
FROM `daycare attendance table`
LEFT JOIN Students
ON `daycare attendance table`.StudentID = Students.StudentID
WHERE Students.SubStatus IN (ka)
ORDER BY `daycare attendance table`.ItemNo DESC LIMIT 10000
```

I am using the IN clause instead of OR as I have done many times

```
Students.SubStatus IN (ka)
```

When I run the query mysql is returning an error of `Unknown column 'ka' in 'where clause'`

Why is it thinking that `ka` is a column and not a value that I am looking for? Am I just to tired and not seeing the obvious?

**SOLVED**

Apparently I have never used a string in a IN clause. You have to have single quotes around a string....duh

Answer (score 2):

You need to put ka in quotes. 'Ka'